# What could be mean the name rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue

I'm interested in why rvalue references are called exactly "rvalue references". How does it relate to `rvalue, prvalue etc` concepts. The section N3797::5/5 says:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2,
>   8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference,
>   and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the
>   expression.

That's an expression in which rvalue reference involves is adjusted to an `lvalue` or an `xvalue`, but not to `rvalue` or `prvalue`.

Comment: It is because the reference *must* be bound to an rvalue.   An lvalue reference may be bound to lvalues or rvalues.

Comment: @MattMcNabb But what about lvalue-to-rvalue standard convertion? Why isn't it performed?

Comment: That is performed during expression evaluation . I don't see what that has to do the question "why are rvalue references called rvalue references".  Your quote talks about how rvalue references are evaluated in an expression. The name "rvalue reference" applies to how the reference is bound, not to what it does in an expression.

Comment: An xvalue is a type of rvalue.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, can you post some code to explain your questions a bit better?

Comment: @RSahu There is no any code. I'm just trying to understand these concepts formally.

Comment: The initialization of references are specified in §8.5.3 [dcl.init.ref]/p5. It explicitly prohibits initializing an rvalue reference from an lvalue expression if the reference's type is reference-related to the expression's type.